What is the value of $\displaystyle\prod_{n=3}^{\infty} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$
While solving a geometry problem, I encountered the infinite product:
$P =\displaystyle\prod_{n=3}^{\infty} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$
This appears to converge to $\approx 0.11494$
Can we show that $P>0$. And what is this value of $P$?
My attempt:
$\ln(P) = \ln\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+\ln\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+\cdots = -\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\tan(x)dx  -\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan(x)dx -\cdots$
So $P>0$ iff the sum of the integrals converge.
I can see graphically that $0 <\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{n}} \tan(x)dx < \frac{2\pi}{n^2}$ for all $n\geq3$ and so it would follow that the sum of the integrals converge and hence $P>0$. However, representing as an integral does not seem to help me find the value of $P$.

how about using $\cos$ as an complex exponential?

Kepler-Bouwkamp constant

If we inscribe a triangle inside a circle, another circle inside the triangle, then inside the circle we inscribe a square, and then another circle inside that square, etc. Then the equation relating the inradius and circumradius of a regular polygon gives the ratio of the final and initial circles as your equation,
$$P =\displaystyle\prod_{n=3}^{\infty} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$$
which is equal to the polygon inscription constant given in (OEIS A085365) as $K = 0.1149420448532962007\ldots$ . You can read more here. Hope this helped
